# How to print the default java classpath from the command line in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, java, classpath

I'm doing some trouble-shooting which requires me to know the default classpath under windows. There's java code which will do this (e.g. http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-do-you-print-java-classpath.html), but I would really like to see something like you would get from `perl -V`:

```
...
@INC:
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.10
/usr/share/perl/5.10
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

Does Java have a quick command-line way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `jdk/bin/jps` should list all the java process IDs running that system
2. subsequently invoke `jdk/bin/jinfo <pid>` to see lot of information... what you require is also there...

Comment: No more direct way to get the info?!

Comment: since the requirement is to get the information from command line, I said this. This is the easiest way in command line. if graphical view is ok, there are tools jvisualvm, jconsole, profilers, etc. From code we can get the same information using System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Answer (score 9):

No need to print the default classpath. In Java, the default classpath is just the current directory:

> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user
>   class path consists of the current directory (.).

([documentation of `java`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html))

*Note:* For completeness' sake: Theree are two other paths where `java` will look for stuff:

- the bootstrap class path
- the extension directory

The bootstrap class path by default points to parts of the JDK, and you almost never want to mess with it (unless you want to override part of the JDK), so you probably should not worry about it. The extension directories are for extending the JDK; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/index.html